# Does the following limit exist? (involving harmonic numbers)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, harmonic-numbers

Let $H_m$ denote the $m$-th harmonic number (with the convention $H_0:=0$).
Fix an integer $n$. Define for $k=0,1,\dots,n-1$ 
$$
d_{n,k}:={1\over{n^2}}\biggl\{\sum_{j=0}^k \bigl(H_n-H_k+H_{n-1}-H_{n-k+j-1} \bigr)^2\\
+ \sum_{j=k+1}^{n-1} \bigl( H_n-H_j+H_{n-1}-H_{n-k-1} \bigr)^2\biggr\},
$$ 
and also
$$
R_n:=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} d_{n,k}.
$$

If it exists, what is $$\lim_{n\to\infty} R_n?$$

Numerical evidence suggests that it might be around $1.28987$.

Comment: Have you tried approximating harmonic numbers with natural logarithms, and using their well-known properties ?

Comment: @Lucian: yes I tried that, unsuccessfully.

Comment: For $k=n-1$, the second part of $d_{n,k}$ is a finite sum from $j=n$ to $j=n-1$. Can I presume that you are using the convention of assigning a zero value to such sums?

Comment: Can you tell in which context this limit arose?